# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I've just upgraded Laravel from 5.0 to 5.1.

I get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()
```

So after some searching I need to change bindShared to a singleton.

I can do this in vendor/illuminate/html/HtmlServiceProvider.php

The issue is, what happens when another dev works on the project and performs a composer install, or I deploy to a server.

How can I persist changes to files in the vendor folder?

Comment: The short answer is that you don't edit anything inside the `vendor` directory. However, that answer isn't exactly good for you as you're currently needing to do so. However, that is, to put it simply, wrong. You shouldn't have to edit anything in vendor to do what you want to, as such it looks like you're therefore probably doing something wrong in your app's code (some kind of hack). What is the exact problem? I don't know L5 very well at all but maybe if you explain what your exact issue is (e.g. give us your code that's calling `bindShared`) maybe we can help diagnose the actual issue.

Comment: The actual issue is that L 5.1 has depreciated bindShared and illuminate still uses it. From the L5 upgrade page: The service container's bindShared method has been deprecated in favor of the singleton method.

Comment: i got it without illuminate/html , to fix it .i execute `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload -o`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Okay based on your comment I see your issue (I should have noticed it sooner as you do mention the HTML component in your question.

The `illuminate/html` component is no longer part of Laravel proper, and hasn't yet been updated to conform to 5.1 standards. In fact, I'm pretty sure it is now officially abandoned by Taylor.

However, you can replace the `illuminate/html` requirement with [laravelcollective/html](https://packagist.org/packages/laravelcollective/html) - that's the official community takeover of illuminate/html and should be a drop-in replacement.

No having to mess with stuff in `vendor`!

Answer (score 11):

`Illuminate/html` is abandoned. Use `Collective/html` instead.

To install it use the following

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"
```

Then in app/app.php file change/add as following 
for providers

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class
```

and for aliases

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue comes due to bindShared() method , just change it in to singleton()

file is located here: /projectname/vendor/illuminate/html/HtmlServiceProvider.php

change on line no : 36 and 49

Comment: The OP knows this and wants to avoid this. Please read the question and comments before posting an answer, especially a late answer.

Comment: @hrbrmstr this question is where google leads you when you search for the error message as seen in the title. Therefore, while not relevant to OP, it is relevant to pretty much everyone else, including me.  This is pretty much like the first result on google being a forum thread where the first reply is "did you google that?".

Answer (score 3):

> The following Laravel features have been deprecated and will be
> removed entirely with the release of Laravel 5.2 in December 2015: ...
>
> > The service container's `bindShared` method has been deprecated in favour
> > of the `singleton` method. ...

ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade

---

So, for example, starting from L5.1 you can safely change:

```
    $this->app->bindShared(UserObserver::class, function ()
    {
        // ... 
    });
```

to:

```
    $this->app->singleton(UserObserver::class, function ()
    {
        // ... 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am Rails developer & new to laravel & its just my first day and got stuck in this Form Builder issue. I have gone through many discussions and posts but got my solution on **https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html**
To use blade form builder (Form::open) we need to change our **composer.json** and add `"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"` in the require block.
Then run **composer update** because then only new dependencies will be available to your project.
Now add 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider', inside config/app.php inside providers block also you need to add

```
'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
      'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
    // ...
  ],
```

inside config/app.php in aliases block.

run php artisan serve
Enjoy Form builder with blade engine.