# "How to fix 'class not found' error in Laravel"

Tags: laravel

I need to create a form in Laravel. When I open the `localhost` it shows this error

> "Class 'Collective\Html\FormFacade' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\softwareProject\test\resources\views\studentForm.blade.php)"

How to fix this?

Comment: Use `composer/dump-autoload`

Comment: sorry i didn't get it.

Comment: @asha_sulaiman check my answer please!

Comment: Can you share your composer.json ?

Comment: @asha_sulaiman did you tried my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `composer.json` file to require `laravelcollective/html`

By using `composer` in your terminal or command prompt type the following:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
```

Second, add this provider to the `providers` array of `config/app.php` as below:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

And finally add two class aliases to the `aliases` array of `config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

For more details check [docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#installation)

**UPDATE:**

If you're getting `[UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint :5.4.0: Invalid version string ":5.4.0"` error then you can insert this entry manually in `composer.json`. And after that then use composer update.

What you need now is just add `"laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*"`, below the row with "laravel/framework":"5.4.*" as below:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*", // Add this entry and then run composer update
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response. btw when i executed the command it gave this error  "[UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse version constraint :5.4.0: Invalid version string ":5.4.0"  . can you help me to solve this?

Comment: Which laravel version you're using

Comment: new version 5.8

Comment: Thank you for updating the asnwer. I tried it but still occuring some errors.this is my composer.json file https://i.stack.imgur.com/8quhd.png

Comment: Please check this @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250211/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-foundation-applicationbindshared